# RXJS Animate While

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'd like to get the mouse coordinate and then animate using requestanimationframe while a `BehaviorSubject` is true.

Any thoughts on where to begin? I'm stuck here:

```
this.isDragging$
    .filter((isDragging: boolean) => isDragging)
    .switchMap(() => Observable.interval(0, animationFrame))
    .takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
    .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(1)
     })
```

However this obviously doesn't stop when the isDragging is false...

Comment: This can give you some idea https://medium.freecodecamp.org/https-medium-com-henry-little-a-reactive-joystick-built-with-rxjs-abfca3668786

Comment: is isDragging and continuous stream which keep emitting while dragging? better provide the code in your question.